# Fullcalendar only loading event after view changed, then wont remove events until view changed again

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I am having issues on my live server with fullcalendar. It was working just fine on localhost.

Basically:

when the page loads, it does an ajax call to load all events into the calendar. When the user selects a location, it redoes that ajax request to update all the events in that location. Which it must a) remove the events and b) load the new events returned from the server.

Here is my code:

on page load:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    fixedWeekCount: false,
    defaultView: 'month',
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.html('');

        var seats_available = (typeof counts[event.post_id] != 'undefined') ? event.seats - counts[event.post_id] : event.seats;

        var dateString = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        var cal = $('#calendar').find('.fc-day-number[data-date="' + dateString + '"]').css('background-color', 'red').addClass('tooltip-here');
        var html = '<div><span>Course: </span><p>' + event.title + '</p><br /><span>Seats Available: </span><p>' + seats_available + ' / ' + event.seats + '</p><br /><span>Price: </span><p>R ' + event.cost.toCurrency(2, '.', ',') + '</p><br /><br /><div class="button"><button type="button" class="primary book-course" data-date="' + dateString + '" >Book Course</button></div></div>';
        Tipped.create('.tooltip-here[data-date="' + dateString + '"]', html, {position: 'bottom'});
      }
  });
```

The get events method:

```
function getEventData() {

  $.ajax({
    url: EVENT.ajaxurl, // this is a variable passed through by wordpress
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      action: 'get_event_data',
      selected_location: $('#location-select').val(),
      security: NINJA_EVNT.security
    },
    success: function( res ) {
      console.log('#location-select', $('#location-select').val());
      console.log('response', res);



      var events_raw = JSON.parse(res.data.posts);
      counts = res.data.counts;
      var events = [];
        console.log('events', events);
      var seats_available = (typeof counts[events_raw.post_id] != 'undefined') ? events_raw.seats - counts[events_raw.post_id] : events_raw.seats;
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents'); // this isn't removing the events anymore
      for(var i = 0; i < events_raw.length; i++) {
          console.log('events_raw[i]', events_raw[i]);
        var obj = {
          post_id: events_raw[i].post_id,
          title: events_raw[i].title,
          start: moment(events_raw[i].start_date).toDate(),
          seats: events_raw[i].seats,
          seats_available: seats_available,
          description: events_raw[i].description,
          cost: events_raw[i].cost,
          eventMouseover : function(data, event, view) {
              var content = '<span class="hint--bottom"><h3>'+events_raw[i].title+'</h3>' +
                  '<p><b>Start:</b> '+moment(events_raw[i].start_date).toDate()+'</p>' +
                  '<p><b>Seats:</b> '+ seats_available +' / ' + events_raw[i].seats + '</p>' +
                  '<p><b>Description</b> '+events_raw[i].description+ '</p></span>';

              tooltip.set({
                  'content.text': content
              })
              .reposition(event).show(event);
          }
        };
        events.push(obj);
        console.log('obj', obj);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', obj, true); // this adds the new events just fine
      }



    },
    error: function( error ) {
      console.log('error', error);
    }
  });
}
```

UPDATE:
Forgot to add, if I reload the events and the events don't remove, if I go to the next month and back, it loads just fine.

Comment: try `console.log(EVENT.ajaxurl);` what does it shows for you?

Comment: @lolka_bolka It works. It returns the right data, the calendar itself doesnt update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that this was just a latency issue. Putting a loading overlay until it had loaded properly and populated the dropdown worked just fine.